# Document preparation in Isabelle

Tags: latex, isabelle

I want to use `isabelle build -D xxx` to produce a LaTeX `.tex` file out of an Isabelle `.thy` file. 
But Isabelle checks all the theory dependencies, and all the related `.thy` files must be involved.

Is it possible that I casually use a `.thy` file that has syntax errors to produce a `.tex` file?  In fact I only need a part of it to write a paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no. The LaTeX generation requires the file to be processed successfully, e.g. due to `notation (latex)` commands, and due to antiquotations.

If you only need parts of your file, simply copy’n’paste it from the generated `.tex` file or, if you want something more automated, have a look at the [Generate TeX Snippets](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/community/Generate_TeX_Snippets) wiki page.

Answer (score 4):

Does that mean you want to write a paper based on a faulty or incomplete formal theory?

The Isabelle document preparation system was intended to publish formal theories that actually work out, with nice typography so that this does not look like "code".  So all the defaults are for producing LaTeX from well-formed and checked theories.

Nonetheless, there are numerous ways to get unofficial LaTeX output from the system.  A very basic mechanism is the `latex` print mode.  Various diagnostic commands of Isabelle allow such print mode specifications in round parentheses, e.g. like this:

```
thm (latex) exI exE
```

or

```
print_statement (latex) exI exE
```

You can do this interactively and copy-paste the output into your raw tex file.  You need to ensure that it gets proper surroundings with environments from the `isabelle.sty` file.